# How could I optimize this function?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to take all values before current and compute skewness on them, so at the end I can have a Series where each row has cumulative skewness of last values.
Note that r series also contains zeroes

```
def skewness_line(r):

    """
    Computes the skewness for each row of the supplied DataFrame
    Returns a Series with the skewness for each row cummulative
    """
    acumulado = pd.Series()
    result = []
    contador = 0
    for i in r: 
        acumulado[contador] = i
        demeaned_r = acumulado - acumulado.mean()
        # use the population standard deviation, so set dof=0
        sigma_r = acumulado.std(ddof=0)
        exp = (demeaned_r**3).mean()
        result.append(exp/sigma_r**3)
        contador += 1
        
    return result
```

Usage example

```
df1['SK'] = skewness(df1['Col_name'])
df1.head()
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several optimizations you can apply here.

1. Adding one element at a time to a Series is quite slow. If you know how much space you'll need in advance, you can use NumPy, and pre-allocate an array of the appropriate size.
2. When computing the mean of the first N elements, it is faster to keep a running sum of the elements so far, and divide that running sum by the count of elements seen so far, rather than repeatedly finding the mean of the same elements.
3. In a similar sense, there is an algorithm to compute sample variance, and therefore standard deviation, without looking back at all of the elements so far. It is called [Welford's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Welford%27s_online_algorithm). As a bonus, Welford's algorithm also gives the cumulative mean.
4. I attempted a similar algorithm, to replace the step which computes `(demeaned_r**3).mean()`, but could not figure out how. I consulted these three sources trying to figure this out: [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Higher-order_statistics) [2](https://github.com/dr-nikolai/online_stat) [3](https://www.osti.gov/biblio/1426900)

   I think you might be computing something different from the standard idea of skewness. This is my best guess.
5. You can use a library called [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) to optimize loops that mainly deal with NumPy arrays.

Code:

```
import numba as nb


@nb.njit()
def skewness_line(array):
    """
    Computes the skewness for each row of the NumPy array
    Returns an array with the skewness for each row cummulative
    """
    N = len(array)
    result = np.zeros(N)
    M = 0
    S = 0
    # Use 1 indexing to make Welford's algorithm a little nicer
    for k in range(1, N + 1):
        x = array[k - 1]
        # Apply welford to get running sigma values. Derived from
        # https://jonisalonen.com/2013/deriving-welfords-method-for-computing-variance/
        delta = x - M
        M += delta / k
        S += (x-M) * delta
        # use the population standard deviation, so set ddof=0
        sigma_r = np.sqrt(S / k)
        demeaned_r = array[:k] - M
        exp = (demeaned_r ** 3).mean()
        if sigma_r != 0:
            result[k-1] = exp/sigma_r**3
        else:
            result[k-1] = np.nan
        
    return result
```

Usage example:

```
print(skewness_line(df['var'].values))
```

Performance comparison, on 100 random values:

```
Original
60.4 ms ± 267 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
@AndrejKesely solution
30.7 ms ± 264 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
My solution
37.7 µs ± 285 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
My solution (without Numba)
1.86 ms ± 34 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

This is roughly 1000x faster than the original.

Comment: Always nice to see `numba` solution :) +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.expanding()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.expanding.html#pandas-series-expanding) + `.apply()`:

```py
def skew(acumulado):
    demeaned_r = acumulado - acumulado.mean()
    # use the population standard deviation, so set dof=0
    sigma_r = acumulado.std(ddof=0)
    exp = (demeaned_r**3).mean()
    return exp / sigma_r**3


df1["SK_new"] = df1["Col_name"].expanding().apply(skew)
print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
   Col_name        SK    SK_new
0         1       NaN       NaN
1         2  0.000000  0.000000
2         3  0.000000  0.000000
3         0  0.000000  0.000000
4         1  0.271545  0.271545
5         2  0.000000  0.000000
6         3 -0.192012 -0.192012
```